# Off-canvas menu animation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a HTML site, and I want to create a off-canvas menu for navigation.
However the code I've written won't work at all.

I have tried to re-write my script and the HTML/CSS document, I've also tried to make a local webbserver to host the html, css and the javascript tosee if that would change anything, but it didn't.

I have also tried to follow some coding guides on youtube and w3schools, but I can't get it to work. Please help me.

Thank you in advance!

```html
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="hdt">

            </div>
            <div id="hdb">
                <span style="cursor: pointer" onclick="openNav">
                    &#9776; Menu
                </span>

                <div id="mysidenav" class="sidenav">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="exit" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
                    <a href="#">Home</a>
                    <a href="#">Parts</a>
                    <a href="#">Services</a>
                    <a href="#">About us</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="contain">

        </div>
        <div id="footer">

        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function openNav() {
            document.getElementById("mysidenav").style.width = "250px";
            document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";
        }

        function closeNav() {
            document.getElementById("mysidenav").style.width = "0";
            document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS file:

```css
#main {
    width: 1500px;
    height: 950px;
    transition: margin-left .5s
}

#header {
    width: 1500px;
    height: 100px;
}

#hdt {
    height: 75px;
    background-color: white;
}

#hdb {
    height: 25px;
    background-color: limegreen;
    border: 1px solid black;
    transition: margin-left .5s;
}

.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-top: 60px;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .exit {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

#contain {
    width: 1500px;
    height: 700px;
}

#footer {
    width: 1500px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: could you be more specific on what doesn't work?

Comment: @Hafnernuss Oh yes sorry, the menu doesn't show up on the screen at all, but if I hover over the button that's supposed to bring it out the cursor does change to pointer, but the menu won't show to the left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to include the opening `<html>` tag in your code. But I guess that's a copy & paste error ;)

To resolve your actual problem, simply change:

```html
<span style="cursor: pointer" onclick="openNav">
       &#9776; Menu
</span>
```

to:

```html
<span style="cursor: pointer" onclick="openNav()">
       &#9776; Menu
</span>
```

Here's a working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/r71n6cs9/12/

Comment: Thank you!

And yes the missing `<html>` tag was a copy & paste error.
But the code works now and thank you for helping me